# How to add randomness to movement of instances using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I used geonodes to make object move in semi-random pattern and point in direction it moves. Then I used another object to scatter many of those objects as instances and point them in different directions.

Now I want to add some randomness to their trajectory so they won't all turn at the same time, but every solution I try just start displacing geometry of instances and don't affect their individual trajectories. Muted nodes is a couple of ideas I tried. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't offset time in the instance. Instances are objects that's share the same object data. In other words, you can't make different instances, because they just the same. Take a look at <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> copies. They are linked, they are instances of the same data, and if you change one of them - the second will be changed also.

Instead of animating the instance and when distribute it on the surface, do the opposite thing: distribute the instance on the surface and then add animation for each instance. You will be abble to add offset to the animation by adding random value to timer

Comment: But they are still gonna be instances, no? And if I add "realise instances" then "set position" will displace geometry instead of moving oriigin points.

Comment: Then you move them and then instance, you move vertices inside the object, and object centers stay in place. Then you move them after instancing, you will move instances itself, it's object centers. Then you realize instance, you convert all geometry from instances into one object, object centers will be lost.

Comment: Aaand I'm lost) sry, I'm not native speaker and can't really get what you're saying

Comment: I try, to explain it using different words: currently, you modify the original cube.002 and then create instances of it in cube.003. Thus all instances get modified in the same way. Instead you should do the modification after the Instances on Points node for every instance differently.

Comment: @AndréZmuda Yes, I got that. Problem is - set position works differently with instances and actual geometry, so I'm either dont really change anythng except for order, since it's still instances or I add "realise instances" and then set position will just displace geometry instead of moving origins points of objects.

Comment: Try Translate Instances node instead of Set Position